# Why is relative url in html src attribute because full path in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image button when you click on it one of the things done is a javascript function is called to modify the image to indicate it has been clicked

HTML:

```
<td><input type="image" onclick="toggleMe(this)" value="Tracks" src="../../images/open.png"/></td>
```

JS:

```
function toggleMe(btn){
    btn.src = btn.src=="../../images/open.png" ? "../../images/close.png" : "../../images/open.png";
}
```

However it didnt work because although src was to set to a relative url the value the javascript function gets is the full path (http:localhost:8080/images/open.png). I fixed this locally by changing function to

```
function toggleMe(btn){
    btn.src = btn.src=="http:localhost:8080/images/open.png" ? "http:localhost:8080/images/close.png" : "http:localhost:8080/images/open.png";
}
```

but this will not work in production environment because full url will be different.

So, does Javascript not receive relative path that was set in the html
How do I fix this in a portable way

Comment: `full url will be different` - how different?

Comment: It would be servername instead of locahost, and probably different portno

Comment: use `/images/open.png` like urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this alternative:

```
function toggleMe(btn){
  var srcStr = btn.src;
  var newImgStr = srcStr.indexOf("open.png")>=0 ? "close.png" : "open.png";
  srcStr = srcStr.replace("open.png", newImgStr);
  btn.src = srcStr;
}
```

Comment: True, thanks - but why the difference between html and javascript value ?

Comment: There is no difference in HTML or JS values as everything resolves to absolute URLs in the browser!! Only thing is that while comparing you should check for the existence of the images rather than checking equality of URLs which will be different for each environment.

Comment: 'There is no difference in HTML or JS values as everything resolves to absolute URLs in the browser!!' - I see, didnt realize that but yeah that makes sense. Are there javascript functins that understand servername, portno parts of url so i could more robustly strip of the 'http:localhost:8080' part

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can obviously parse a URL in JS but you need not take the overhead of processing. Instead you can leverage JS to just check the existence of a specific string and then replace it (as per your use case).

Comment: Hmm , if I was write a java application (not javascript) I would consider that check youve done as rather hacky

Comment: And why would that be?

Comment: Because you are only checking a part of the path and assuming that gives you a unique answer, also regarding performance you are then having to do a relatively expensive replace within an existing string instead of just setting to a new string.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I do not agree. If you are mentioning about memory intensive operations, you should provide some statistics to support your statement. Can you try that from Java and let me know the statistics? Also, if you do an `indexOf` image name, then you would always get an unique value unless you name your image something like `/images` which never happens.

Comment: I dont see how my statenment is any different to your ubnstantiated ' need not take the overhead of processing', but its clear that doing a replace and then a set is certainly slower than just a set  (even if the difference is minute). Ive marked your question as correct as it works, thankyou but I would like to know how to get the path relative to hsotname:port

Comment: @PaulTaylor for that you need to use server side programming. In JS, you can also parse a URL, take a look at this - https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561. BTW, my answer is not marked as correct yet :)

Comment: thanks I did mark yours as correct but then changed to the answer as that was slightly more succinct but since you have now given me this useful info about url parsing Ive marked your question as correct again.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced these problems here is how solve them

First of all I identify what is different between two urls and in your case I can write this

```
 function toggleMe(btn){
btn.src = btn.src.indexOf("images/open.png")>-1 ? 
    btn.src.replace("images/open.png","images/close.png"):btn.src.replace("images/close.png","images/open.png");
}
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer so marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Actually slighty wrong, if not open.png then close.png in which case needs to be moved back to open i.e btn.src = btn.src.indexOf("images/open.png")>-1 ? btn.src.replace("images/open.png","images/close.png"):btn.src.replace("images/close.png","images/open.png");

Comment: Thank you @Paul Taylor I have edited the answer in order to add the seconde replace...